# Update command output

Tags: php, mysql

I want to write an update command when the records did not exist. After a message

```
    mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE system SET count  ='1'   where  code ='929'");
```

I mean if there was a record field of 929 code updates the information when otherwise give a message

Comment: Normally you capture the execution result and check the modified rows count.

Comment: You should probably update the tags to include the name of the language you're using to access the mysql database. I'd guess PHP, but that little code could easily be perl or- actually, that's also valid bash. I mean, it wouldn't do what you'd expect, but if two commands were carefully named this would work. Strange world we live in.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$num_modified = mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE system SET count  ='1'   where  code ='929'");
if ($num_modified != 1) { 
 echo "Failed to modify!";
}
```